# How to align three cards to center in a row using CCS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, alignment, row, card

I was building a website, but I got a problem. When I was trying to align three cards in one row to the center, they stayed on the left.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Ramndom1</h3>
        <p class="card-text">hfejhgfjhejhfvhjhefgvfjhefvfvevjhfvfvejhvfvjhf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Random2</h3>
        <p class="card-text">fheguighefgheghhjfggfefgghf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Random3</h3>
        <p class="card-text">fhekfhejkfjhegfghfjhegbfjhfjhefgfehf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
  .column {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
.card {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #8fb1ff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 63px/84px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card-text {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 24px/32px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

I can't align it using this code. What can be the problem?
I tried to use justify-content, but it didn't work. I have3 no idea what else I can do.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: which center? vertical center? or just horizontal center? why so complicated if css-grid would do it way easier by also allowing the switch to hamburger layout with media queries much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

To `.card` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```css
.column {
  width: calc(33% - 30px);
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
.card {
  background: #8fb1ff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 63px/84px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card-text {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 24px/32px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Ramndom1</h3>
        <p class="card-text">hfejhgfjhejhfvhjhefgvfjhefvfvevjhfvfvejhvfvjhf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Random2</h3>
        <p class="card-text">fheguighefgheghhjfggfefgghf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-title">Random3</h3>
        <p class="card-text">fhekfhejkfjhegfghfjhegbfjhfjhefgfehf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```